# Rspec test with login devise just working one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise

I'm trying to test some views with devise and rspec. In this test, the first one passes. The second is redirect to sign_in page.

The login_as just working in the first test.
If I add 3 tests the last fails and the first 2 passes.
If I change `:all` to `:each` the first one fails and the second passes

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe StoresController, type: :controller do
    context "with valid params" do
        user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
        before(:all) do
            login_as(user, :scope => :user)
        end

        it "renders the index template" do
            get :index
            expect(response).to render_template("index")
        end

        it "creates a new store" do
            get :new
            expect(response).to render_template("new")
        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`before(:all)` will run only once. That's why only the first test pass.

Use `before(:each)` or simply `before do`

Also, the user variable should be created for each test, meaning that it should be declared inside the before block:

```
before do
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
  login_as(user, :scope => :user)
end
```